# Why Deep Q networks algorithm performs only one gradient descent step?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn

Why dqn algorithm performs only one gradient descent step, i.e. trains for only one epoch? Would not it benefit from more epochs, won’t its accuracy improve with more epochs?

Comment: I was sure one runs it till convergence?

Comment: @Estradiaz DQN paper states in Algortihm 1 there is only one gradient step on a minibatch. Moreover, all implementations I have seen so far train for only one epoch.

Comment: @Estradiaz M is the total number of episodes one plays, not necessarily stopping criteria. T is the number of time steps in a given episode. Every time step DQN trains on a small minibatch, say 32 samples (paper’s hyperparameter) for only one gradient descent step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time efficiency.

In theory, in the policy iteration / evaluation scheme, you should wait until convergence before moving to the next update. However, this can (a) never happen, (b) take too much. 
So people typically do one single step with a small learning rate in the hope that the critic (Q) is not "too wrong".

You could try more steps, but in general how many gradient steps to do is a design choice, and they probably found that this works the best.